# powershell - classes - calling constructor inside it's own class and returning it

Tags: powershell, class, constructor

I'm trying to call the constructor inside a method to create a new and return it.
Unfortunaly it doesn't work and don't get any error's.
Because I'm used to other languages I'm doing something wrong but don't now what.
Is there somebody who could explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
Or is there another way to get what I need?

```
    cls

class Matrix {
    [int]$some_number

    Matrix(){
        Write-Host "No param's given"
    }

    Matrix($nr){
        $this.some_number = $nr
    }

    thins2do($thing){
        if ($thing.GetType().name -eq "Matrix"){
            #[Matrix]::New(3)
            $temp_matrix = [Matrix]::New(3)
            return $temp_matrix
        }Else{
            Write-Host "You are trying to do the wrong thing"
        }
    }
}

$matrix1 = [Matrix]::New(1)
$matrix1

$matrix2 = [Matrix]::New(2)
$matrix2

$matrix3 = $matrix1.thins2do($matrix2)
$matrix3
```

Comment: The error message immediately tells you what's wrong: "Invalid return statement within void method". Declare the function as `[Matrix] things2do($thing)`, and replace the `Write-Host` with `throw` (otherwise you'd be required to return a value). Better yet, instead of checking the type of `$thing` manually, you can simply give the parameter a type instead (`[Matrix] things2do([Matrix] $thing)`).

Comment: Thanks, this give's me some insite.
Later in the code I also want to do something like this :
    $matrix3 = $matrix1.thins2do(2)
So that's why I had the "GetType().name" - check and Else statement.
Is there Also a work around for this?

Comment: Yes, overload the function: declare a separate `[Matrix] things2do([int] $thing)`. You can even have this one call the other `things2do`, if that's convenient. Note that if you're going to do a lot of numerical calculations (which these names imply), PowerShell may not be the most appropriate language since it lacks operator overloading (which is not a dealbreaker, but *is* convenient for making things readable -- `a * b` is generally preferred over `a.multiply(b)`). A language like C# does. (And there are numerical libraries readily available for it.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 2 @Jeroen Mostert ==>

```
    cls

class Matrix {
    [int]$some_number

    Matrix(){
        Write-Host "No param's given"
    }

    Matrix($nr){
        $this.some_number = $nr
    }

    [Matrix]thins2do([Matrix]$thing){
        $temp_matrix = [Matrix]::New(3)
        return $temp_matrix
    }

    [Matrix]thins2do([int]$thing){
        $temp_matrix = [Matrix]::New(4)
        return $temp_matrix
    }
}

$matrix1 = [Matrix]::New(1)
$matrix1

$matrix2 = [Matrix]::New(2)
$matrix2

$matrix3 = $matrix1.thins2do($matrix2)
$matrix3

$matrix4 = $matrix1.thins2do(2)
$matrix4
```